# Laravel define default layout from controller in good way

Tags: php, laravel

I googled two hours, but not found answer. Maybe you can help.

When I define in **MyController**:

```
class MyController extends Base_Controller {
    public $layout = 'layouts.default';

    public function get_index() {
        $entries = Entry::all();
        return View::make('entries.index')
            ->with('entries', $entries);
        }
    }
}
```

In **entries\index.blade.php**:

```
@section('content')
    <h1>Test</h1>
@endsection
```

And in **layouts\default.blade.php**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is displaying. And I don't understand why. When I am replacing in **MyController** return part with:

```
$this->layout->nest('content', 'entries.index', array(
    'entries' => $entries
));
```

Then all is working, but.. It looks not clean and I don't like it. When adding in every view `@layout('layouts.default')` all is working good too, but it is not DRY. For example, in RoR I don't need to do such things in Controller.

How can define in `MyController` one layout and use `return View::make` (I think that this is right way) or how can do it better?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To use layouts in controllers, you must specify:

```
public $layout = 'layouts.default';
```

You can also not return in the method as it will override the use of $layout. Instead, to embed your content within the layout you use:

```
$this->layout->nest('content', 'entries.index', array('entries' => $entries));
```

No need to return anything in your method now. This will fix it.

---

Edit:

"Beautiful Ways?"

```
$this->layout->nest('content', 'entries.index')->with('entries', $entries);


$this->layout->content = View::make('entries.index')->with('entries', $entries);


$this->layout->entries = $entries;
$this->layout->nest('content', 'entries.index');
```

Comment: Yes - it is working as I wrote in question post, but IMHO it is ugly. There are no clearer/simpler way?

Comment: @Orbitum what exactly is ugly?

Comment: It is strange to do `$this->layout->nest('section', 'viewfile')` for each action. So I want to know - is there more laconic way to render view with/without section and variables or no. If there are no shorter way - then I will not search more.

Comment: Remember you can chain the with() and nest() methods. `$this->layout->with('title', 'Hello World')->nest('content', 'entries.index', compact('entries'))`

Comment: $this->layout->nest('content', 'entries.index')->with('entries', $entries); not working.. entries is undefined

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
public $layout = 'layouts.default';
```

Here's the link [Templating - The Basics](http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#the-basics)

Now you can return your layout like this

```
$view = View::make('entries.index')->with('entries', $entries);
$this->layout->content = $view->render();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 class BaseController extends Controller {

/**
 * Setup the layout used by the controller.
 *
 * @return void
 */

/*Set a layout properties here, so you can globally
  call it in all of your Controllers*/
protected $layout = 'layouts.default';

protected function setupLayout()
{
    if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
    {
        $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
    }
}
```

}

class HomeController extends BaseController {

```
public function showHome()
{   
    /*now you can control your Layout it here */
     $this->layout->title= "Hi I am a title"; //add a dynamic title 
     $this->layout->content = View::make('home');
}
```

}

Ref:
http://teknosains.com/i/tutorial-dynamic-layout-in-laravel-4

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.