# Laravel: Just a view and a layout - hassle-free?

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am not a big fan of template engines like Laravel's Blade. It is mainly because I taught myself to use PHP as the templating engine and I feel very confortable with it. So I wish to stick with it.

But unfortunately, Laravel's docs do not state how I can just use PHP templates and have a pre-defiend layout. All the examples show a line that extends from the default template. This certainly was easier in Yii...

Is there a way to specify an all-existant layout and then just render my views into that - or will I have to write my own cod

I saw this question: [Laravel define default layout from controller in good way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501922/laravel-define-default-layout-from-controller-in-good-way)
But it's pretty dated. Thats why I ask here again.